# PNG image data has size 0 x 0 on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, png

I have a png file created in Pixelmator on OS X that I would like to use in my iOS app. This image displays fine in OSX, and when I create an NSData object with the URL of the file, the quicklook preview in the debugger also displays the image perfectly, but when I try to create a UIImage with the following

```
    NSURL* imageURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: name withExtension: @"png"];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: imageURL]; //at this line, quicklooking "Data" shows the image I want
    image = [UIImage imageWithData: data]; //this is the relevant line, where the failure is logged

    if (!image) {
        //this has the same result
        NSURL* imageURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"imageNotFound" withExtension: @"png"];
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: imageURL];
        image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
    }
}
```

I get this error message

```
<Error>: CGImageCreateWithImageProvider: invalid image size: 0 x 0.
```

A final wrinkle; a similar image which prints this error displays perfectly when used as a texture with GLKTextureLoader.

Comment: What happens when you try and use `[UIImage imageNamed:name]`?

Comment: Same result. That was the first method I tried.

Comment: Are you sure the image really is a valid png? Perhaps you saved it in a different format but used the extension png. Export the image from Pixelmator again and be sure you really export it in the PNG format.

Comment: If you want to be sure, find the image in the Finder and right-click and select "Get Info". Make sure it says "Portable Network Graphics" next to "Kind".

Comment: It is indeed a png. I have tried several images.